# What does the expression `p[i&1]+=v,p` mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was practicing my javascript with CodeFights and after I finished an exercise I saw this function as a result:

```
// Subject : 
// Several people are standing in a row and need to be divided into two teams. 
// The first person goes into team 1, the second goes into team 2, 
// the third goes into team 1 again, the fourth into team 2, and so on.
// You are given an array of positive integers - the weights of the people. 
// Return an array of two integers, where the first element is the total weight of 
// team 1, and the second element is the total weight of team 2 
// after the division is complete.

// Example :
// For a = [50, 60, 60, 45, 70], the output should be
// alternatingSums(a) = [180, 105].

// answer
alternatingSums = a => a.reduce((p,v,i) => (p[i&1]+=v,p), [0,0])
```

I don't understand what `p[i&1]+=v,p` means.

Comment: `p&1` alters between 0 and 1 for odd and even numbers of p (it looks only at bit position 0 with value 1). It does exactly what the name and comment says, it sums up every second position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` symbol is a bitwise binary operator.

To understand what would happen, you have to convert each item to binary.

```
   | i (decimal) | i (binary) | i & 1 |
   |-------------|------------|-------|
   |           0 |          0 |     0 |
   |           1 |          1 |     1 |
   |           2 |         10 |     0 |
   |           3 |         11 |     1 |
   |           4 |        100 |     0 |
   |           5 |        101 |     1 |
```

Effectively, every even number will be transformed to 0, and every odd number will be transformed to 1.

If I was trying to achieve that outcome, I personally would have used the modulus operator (`%`)

```
 p[i%2] += v;
```

But that's just me.

---

The other part is that there are two statements separated by a comma:

```
 (p[i&1]+=v,p)
```

That's saying "Perform this action, then return `p`. It's shorthand for:

```
alternatingSums = a => a.reduce((p,v,i) => { 
                                              p[i&1]+=v;
                                              return p;
                                           }, 
                                [0,0])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks for an element of the `p` array that has index of `i&1` - it is a bitwise AND operation. Then, increments its value by a value of `v` variable. Finally, returns the value of `p` variable.